# group similar results together

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm looking for a way to group similar results together.

I have a table with a lot of bands images. Each images name are identified with the band's name, followed by a number. Example:

```
Metallica 1
Metallica 2
Iron Maiden 1
Iron Maiden 2
Iron Maiden 3
Pink Floyd 1
```

I'm looking for a way to group the results together. Something that would look like that:

```
Metallica (2 results)
Iron Maiden (3 results)
Pink Floyd (1 result)
```

So far i have this:

```
$asql = "SELECT * FROM bands WHERE GROUP BY image";
$ares = mysql_query($asql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ares)) {
$image = $row['image'];
echo "<a href=\"view_more_images.php?band=$image\">$image (X results)</a>";
}
```

But it only groups together the items that has exactly the same name

Comment: I think Primarily you have an syntax error in there  You have used where with no condition , give your table structure to check out with

Comment: ..`GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(image,' ',1)`..

Comment: actully this is better `GROUP BY SubStr(image, 1, LENGTH(myColumn) - 2)` as long as you dont go past 9

Answer (score 2):

If image contains the string "BAND NUMBER", you should consider add one column containing only the band name and group by this column.

Anyways, you can ignore the last token with the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(image, LENGTH(image) - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(image))+1) bandname,
  COUNT(image)
FROM bands
GROUP BY bandname
```

Comment: excellent answer, wasa trying to do something like this myself. You beat me to it haha